# Highcharts column chart not rendering in Edge

Tags: highcharts, microsoft-edge

I created line and column charts, everything is working perfectly in local machine. However, when I moved to production, column chart was not displaying the bars. In Chrome it is working perfectly, but in Edge and IE it is not showing.

I searched a lot on Google, but nothing worked. Most of the sites suggest adding below tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
and 
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your charts on online editor which I could debug? Or send a link to your website?

Comment: I can't because the application is on internal corporate LAN not on the internet

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test the official sample of HighCharts on my side with Edge and IE browser.

Based on my testing results, charts are working fine with IE and Edge browser.

sample code:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

    }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 310px; 
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
    height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
 font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
 margin: 10px auto;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 500px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
 font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        A basic column chart compares rainfall values between four cities.
        Tokyo has the overall highest amount of rainfall, followed by New York.
        The chart is making use of the axis crosshair feature, to highlight
        months as they are hovered over.
    </p>
</figure>
```

Result with IE and Edge browser.

[image]

[image]

It can possible that the issue is in your customized code or there are some settings on that machine causing this issue.

I suggest you check for any errors or warnings in the console of the browser. It can give an idea about the issue.

If the issue persists then I suggest you post a sample code to test the issue. Also let us know, which version of IE and Edge you are using for this test.

Comment: Actually my charts work perfectly on Chrome, but the issue ihe column chart does not show in Edge. the spline shows in all browsers.

Comment: Following is the Console logs. But I already enabled CROS in my Startup.cs, but i think this has nothing to do with my issue. 
 CSS3121: The media query -ms-viewport has been deprecated.

 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
GET - http://localhost:26203/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0

 CSS3116: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted.
fontawesome-webfont.woff (1,1)

Comment: From the console raport it seems like the issue is not related to Highcharts.

Comment: There is no information available in your console logs which shows any issue for Highcharts. Are you using Iframe to display this chart or the data is coming from any other site? For testing purposes, try to lower down the security settings level in Internet options and again check the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I am not using Iframe, the data is coming from internal web api same as the other charts. I minimized security settings but still not showing. And it works perfectly in Chrome but not in Edge.

Comment: and I checked the data is coming when i print using console.log().

Comment: Is any other Hightchart is working with Edge browser? try to pass the static data to the chart which is not showing. It can help to narrow down the issue of whether issue is related to a chart or issue is something else.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT can I see your highcharts package names in package.json ?

Comment: I am running the highchart example in the HTML file. so I don't have package.json file. Does passing the static data to chart worked on your side?

Comment: Hi. I figured the issue long time ago. I was using function from the internet to generate colors codes randomly, the color code should be 6 digits but that function was generating 1 less digit so Edge didn't recognize the colors (but wasn't an issue for chrome though). I used another function that generated colors correctly and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for updating us with the answer to the said question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Add one more }); as the last line of code....

...
name: 'Berlin',
data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8,   51.1]

```
  }]
```

});
**});**